# How to redirect the raw_input to stderr and not stdout?

Tags: python, io, python-2.x

I want to redirect the `stdout` to a file. But This will affect the `raw_input`.  I need to redirect the output of `raw_input` to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  How can I do that?

Comment: play around with `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect `stdout` to `stderr` temporarily, then restore.

```
import sys

old_raw_input = raw_input
def raw_input(*args):
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = sys.stderr
        return old_raw_input(*args)
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: Are there any simple way to do this.

Comment: You could easily write a context manager, so you can write `with swapping_stdout:`. And you could easily write a decorator that just wraps the function in that `with` statement. But if this is the only place you're doing it, it won't be any simpler. (See [here](http://pastebin.com/5L9YhnHn).) If you want a general-purpose attr-swapping context, that's easy… but you'd have to pass it the namespace and the attr name as a string, like `with swapping_attr(sys, 'stdout', sys.stderr):`, which I don't think is an improvement. (MacroPy could make it nice, but I wouldn't use MacroPy just for this…)

Comment: Also, a common trick for this specific case is to use `sys.__stdout__` instead of stashing `old_stdout`.

Comment: @abarnert, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to use `sys.__old_stdout__` (not used `sys.__stdout__` because in Python 3.x, there's already [`sys.__stdout__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__) even though this is Python-2.x question)

Comment: @falsetru: `sys.__stdout__` exists (and is documented) in at least 2.6+, not just 3.x. And it's always the original value of `sys.stdout` at the start of the program. It can be hacky/dangerous to use it this way if you have nested redirections (because instead of restoring the outer redirection you restore the original stdout), but for what the OP is looking for I think it's fine.

Comment: @falsetru: Why use `sys.__old_stdout__` not just a local variable `old_stdout`

Comment: @Samuel, I misunderstood abarnert's comment. reverted the code to use `old_stdout`.

Answer (score 19):

The only problem with `raw_input` is that it prints the prompt to stdout. Instead of trying to intercept that, why not just print the prompt yourself, and call `raw_input` with no prompt, which prints nothing to stdout?

```
def my_input(prompt=None):
    if prompt:
        sys.stderr.write(str(prompt))
    return raw_input()
```

And if you want to replace `raw_input` with this:

```
import __builtin__
def raw_input(prompt=None):
    if prompt:
        sys.stderr.write(str(prompt))
    return __builtin__.raw_input()
```

(For more info, see the docs on [`__builtin__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html), the module that `raw_input` and other [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) are stored in. You usually don't have to `import` it, but there's nothing in the docs that guarantees that, so it's better to be safe…)

In Python 3.2+, the module is named [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) instead of `__builtin__`. (Of course 3.x doesn't have `raw_input` in the first place, it's been renamed [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), but the same idea could be used there.)

Comment: `sys.stderr.write(str(prompt))` should be used instead to make it behave more like [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Comment: @falsetru: Yeah, I think you're right about that. But for your edit, [`__builtin__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) is the right name; `__builtins__` is the CPython-specific name for the module-level object that's either `__builtin__` or `__builtin__.__dict__`. However, I'm not sure `__builtins__` is guaranteed to be there without an `import`, so I'll add that.

Comment: You're right. I just confirm that `__builtins__` exists in CPython (2.7.6), PyPy (2.1), IronPython (2.7.4), but not in Jython (2.5.4). Thank you again.

Comment: @falsetru: Well, it exists on `__main__`, but try different kinds of modules (builtins like `sys`, C extension modules like `cPickle`, Java and .NET imports, normal Python modules like `pickle`, both kinds of packages).

Comment: Jython raised `AttributeError` for any kind of access to `__builtins__` (including java packages like `java.lang.__builtins__`, `java.io.__builtins__`).   Also accessing `sys.__builtins__` in 4 implementations raised `AttributeError`.

Comment: Accessing `cPickle.__builtins__` yields module object in CPy,PyPy,IronPy.  `pickle.__builtins` yields dict object in CPy,IronPy, module object in PyPy.

Comment: Accessing through .NET module (for example `clr.__builtins__`) caused `AttributeError`.

Comment: Since Python 3.2 module and namespace renamed to [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/builtins.html?highlight=builtins#module-builtins)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Of course in 3.2+ there is no `raw_input` to replace either. :) But yeah, it's worth mentioning.

Comment: This approach does not interact well with `readline` (which IMO is one of the main reasons to use `raw_input`/`input`). Entering a character and pressing backspace or Ctrl+U erases the entire line, including the prompt, I'm guessing because `readline` doesn't know where it's supposed to erase up to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)

```
import getpass

value=getpass.getpass("Enter Password: ")
print(value)
```

This will print the content `value` to stdout and `Enter Password:`  to stderr.

Tested and works with python 2.7 and 3.6.

This okay for a password but bad for most other instances: The user won't know if the console is accepting the input up until he presses the `Enter`-Key.

Comment: `getpass` is for entering passwords; it specifically does not echo input.  Not echoing input for non-passwords is a bad user experience.

Comment: @jamesdlin You are absolutely right. I've updated the example. Ty for the hint.