# What's the best practice for writing to the screen separately from stdout?

Tags: python, input, stdout, stderr

I'm writing a data processing script that will write the output to stdout, so the usage is like `myscript.py > outfile.csv`

As the processing is done, there is some user interaction required: a few informative  lines to be printed along with input to be gathered (just yes/no entered by the user).

What's the best practice for displaying this stuff on the screen? It can't go to stdout, since that is getting redirected to the file. Should I just use sys.stderr.write()? How do I use that with raw_input()? Or am I missing a better way? Or should I just write the script so that the name of the output file is taken as an argument? (but I'd like to be able to pipe the output to other scripts).

Comment: Makes more sense that stuff that should go to a specific file, should be written to that file explicitly by your script.. then you can worry about directing stdout and stderr to other places.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any "best practice" for what you're trying to do... seems kind of like a hack that could backfire on you. The only way I can think of is writing to stderr, and that's not a great solution.

Comment: Irrespective of implementing this in Python, this would be a very strange way for a command-line tool to behave. Pretty much impossible actually, short of writing to `stderr`.

Comment: You wouldn't be alone in using standard error for prompts to the user; that's where `bash` and other shells print the prompt.

Comment: `raw_input` also has [issues with readline and stdout / stderr being redirected](http://bugs.python.org/issue1927); better not redirect and use `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK thanks for input everyone, I'll change the way it works and just take the output filename a command line argument. I think I was trying to have it half work like a traditional unix command line tool, but not all the way, which was a bad idea.

In terms of an answer for what I was trying to do, looks like I could have temporarily redirected stdout to stderr at certain times, following this: [How to redirect the raw_input to stderr not stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202403/how-to-redirect-the-raw-input-to-stderr-not-stdout)