# raw_input() prompt disappears when redirecting output to file

Tags: python

I am writing a CLI that accepts an email and password for auth.
The email prompt uses `raw_input()` and the password prompt uses `getpass()` for obfuscation.

This setup works fine when outputting directly to console, but falters when redirecting the output to a log file.

### Sample code:

```py
    user_email = raw_input('Email: ')
    user_password = getpass('Password: ')
```

### Sample output without redirection:

```
$ python script_that_does_stuff.py

Email: me@email.com
Password: 

Doing stuff...
```

### Sample output with redirection:

```
$ python script_that_does_stuff.py > stuff.log
```

Because I *know* that it's expecting a user input here, I can type the email, hit enter, and then it will show:

```
$ python script_that_does_stuff.py > stuff.log
me@email.com
Password:
```

After inputting a password, it continues as usual, however the log shows the following:

```
$ cat stuff.log

Email:Doing stuff...
```

### Question:

How can I force the `raw_input()` prompt to show up in console like the `getpass()` prompt does when redirecting output to a file?

### Environment

This script lives in a legacy Python 2.7 codebase, and is run primarily on Mac OS systems, occasionally Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203064/3900915) on another question seems to work for me.

In short, create a custom input function:

```py
def email_input(prompt=None):
    if prompt:
        sys.stderr.write(str(prompt))
    return raw_input()
```

The calling code then becomes:

```py
    user_email = email_input('Email: ')
    user_password = getpass('Password: ')
```

This results in both the Email and Password prompts being sent to stderr (printing to console), and not messing with the redirected log output.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) `getpass([prompt[, stream]])` has the second optional parameter which indicates output stream to print the prompt to (`stderr` by default).

When you redirect the output (`stdout`) the prompt is still printed to `stderr` for `getpass` but `raw_input` does not support setting an output stream so its prompt is redirecting to to the target file.

So to solve your issue, you have to print your prompt to `stderr` for email as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `sys.stdout` temporarily to write to the terminal. For example,

```
import contextlib
import sys


@contextlib.contextmanager
def output_to_terminal():
    try:
        with open("/dev/tty") as f:
            sys.stdout = f
            yield
    finally:
        # Ensure sys.stdout is restored in the event of an error
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


with output_to_terminal():
    x = raw_input("> ")
print(x)
```

(This was derived independently; you may want to check source for Python 3's `redirect_stdout`, also found in the `contextlib` module, and back port it for your use.)